# How to push all set of record into one array using MongoDB query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to push all records into one array while executing the mongoDB query. I am explaining my query below.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"Customer.StoreCode":"CMHB"}
    },
    {
        $group: {_id : "$Customer.CustomerMobile", "data" : {"$first" : "$$ROOT"}}
    },
    {
        $project: {
            OrderNumber:"$data.OrderNumber",
            OrderStatus:"$data.OrderStatus",
            OrderType:"$data.OrderType",
            CreatedAt:"$data.CreatedAt",
            CustomerMobile: "$data.Customer.CustomerMobile",
            CustomerLastName:"$data.Customer.CustomerLastName",
            CustomerFirstName:"$data.Customer.CustomerFirstName",
            StoreCode:"$data.Customer.StoreCode",
            TransactionId:"$data.PaymentDetails.TransactionId",
            PaymentStatus:"$data.PaymentDetails.PaymentStatus",
            PaymentAmount:"$data.PaymentDetails.PaymentAmount",
            ItemNos: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$data.Products" }, then: { $size: "$data.Products" }, else: "NA"} }
        }
    }
])
```

Here I am getting Some records as per store code and mobile no. Here I need to push all records into one array using that same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has the function toArray() you can do this

```
db.getCollection().toArray();
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/